# Can't send an email through url_launcher

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to send an email whenever a user clicks on an individual's email address. However, I ran into an error. I am testing through the Android emulator. Doesn't it work since there is no mail app on the emulator?

This is the error I get:

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent { mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=Default%20subject&body=Default%20body }, null, null))
```

Here is the code:

```
sendEmail(String email) async {
    String? encodeQueryParameters(Map<String, String> params) {
      return params.entries
          .map((e) =>
              '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}')
          .join('&');
    }

    final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
        scheme: 'mailto',
        path: '$email',
        query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
          'subject': 'Default subject',
          'body': 'Default body',
        }));

    await launch(emailLaunchUri.toString());
  }
```

I call it like this:

```
onTap: () {
   setState(() {
     sendEmail('example@gmail.com');
   });
},
```

I have configured Android and IOS.

Answer (score 2):

For API `>=30`, you need to add in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

You can find more info from [Configuration](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#configuration) section.

Comment: Thanks. But I have the configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: what is value `emailLaunchUri` ? Can you print it out?

Comment: Sorry. The code was cut off in the post. But I'm trying to pass in an argument into the function of sendEmail(String email) async {....}

Comment: can you print out  `emailLaunchUri` ?

Answer (score 1):

dependencies:
flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.2

---

**Example:**

```
final Email email = Email(
  body: 'Email body',
  subject: 'Email subject',
  recipients: ['example@example.com'],
  cc: ['cc@example.com'],
  bcc: ['bcc@example.com'],
  attachmentPaths: ['/path/to/attachment.zip'],
  isHTML: false,
);
```

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);

---

**Setup:**

With Android 11, package visibility is introduced that alters the ability to query installed applications and packages on a user’s device. To enable your application to get visibility into the packages you will need to add a list of queries into your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<manifest package="com.mycompany.myapp">
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use below function for handling email try using it, for sending email through android/ ios using flutter and launch function

```
launchMail(String toMailId, String subject, String body) async {
  final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto', path: toMailId, query: "subject=$subject&body=$body");

  String a = _emailLaunchUri
      .toString()
      .replaceAll("+", "%20")
      .replaceAll("%2520", "%20");

  if (await canLaunch(a)) {
    await launch(a);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $a';
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the Platform error.

Comment: if that's the problem then setup of android/ios is not done properly, check your sdk version and follow the steps for package setup of url_launcher @Kevin